# What is the status of multiple hadiths that are sahih mursal?

Tags: quran, hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

If there was a hadith that is narrated through only mursal chains, would it still be considered authentic if many of those chains were sahih?

Comment: I guess what you are meaning to ask about is the status of a hadith that was provided by several mursal chains or each "version" or "instance" of it was compiled or transmitted as a mursal hadith is that correct? Do you have any example?

Comment: Futher it could be helpful to explain what you mean by mursal, because the terminology was only agreed upon after ibn Salah, before there were 4 different definitions of the term.